# How can I use tidy evaluation in this example?

Tags: r, tidy, tidyeval

I havea  tibble which looks like

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tibble(
  y1 = 10:12,
  y2 = 3:5,
  n1 = rep(100, 3),
  n2 = rep(100, 3)
)
```

and a function which operates on each of these four columns

```
f <- function(y1, n1, y2, n2){
  log(y1/n2) - log(y2/n2)
}
```

I want to use `f` in another function `g`, which calls `f` like

```
g <- function(data, y1, n1, y2, n2){
  
  
  list(
    result_of_f = f(y1, n1, y2, n2)
  )
}


d %>% 
  g(y1, n1, y2, n2)

## Expected outout
##$result_of_f
## [1] 1.2039728 1.0116009 0.8754687
```

This code does not run as it is written, it needs tidy evaluation to work in the way I want it to.  However, I'm a bit confused as to which tidy evaluation to use.  In `g`, the computation of `result_of_f` needs  a data context (something like `with(data, f(y1, n1, y2, n2))`.  How can I use tidy evaluation to get my expected output?

EDIT: The list I've presented in `g` is to be used in downstream computations, it will not be the final output.  I've simply asked for this output in this minimal working example to make it minimal.

Comment: ```d %>% 
  g(., .$y1, .$n1, .$y2, .$n2)``` might work.

Comment: Use `do.call('g', d)`  and you don't need the list wrapping i.e. `f(y1, n1, y2, n2)` is enough

Comment: @akrun the function's signature needs to look as I've presented it, else I wouldn't have asked and would have used your solution or the one presented in the initial comment

Answer (score 0):

The exposition operator (`%$%`) may be useful in this case

```
library(magrittr)
d %$%
  g(, y1, n2, y2, n2)
$result_of_f
[1] 1.2039728 1.0116009 0.8754687
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base function `with()`.

```r
with(d, g(y1, n1, y2, n2))
```